# отладка с gdb. Qt 5.15.2. Linux. подвисание

Tags: linux, qt5, gdb

Среда:

- Fedora 35
- gcc 11.2.1
- gdb 11.1
- Qt 5.15.2

Пытаюсь отлаживать предварительно скомпиленное в отладочном режиме приложение.

Запускаю: gdb ./<приложение>.

Потом run.

Подвисает на Downloading -0.00 MB separate debug info for /lib64/libLLVM-13.so

Долго висит а потом сваливается

```
Thread 7 "QDBusConnection" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffd9ffb640 (LWP 55079)]
0x00007ffff597973f in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fffc80100d0, nfds=4, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
Downloading 0.00 MB source file /usr/src/debug/glibc-2.34-12.fc35.x86_64/io/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c
29    return SYSCALL_CANCEL (poll, fds, nfds, timeout);
```

В чем может быть причина?

Полный лог:

```
gdb ./beatFreqTest
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 11.1-5.fc35
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./beatFreqTest...
Reading symbols from /home/_____/beatFreqTest.debug...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/___/beatFreqTest 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[New Thread 0x7fffe46e3640 (LWP 55074)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdbfff640 (LWP 55075)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdb7fe640 (LWP 55076)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdaffd640 (LWP 55077)]
[New Thread 0x7fffda7fc640 (LWP 55078)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd9ffb640 (LWP 55079)]
Downloading -0.00 MB separate debug info for /lib64/libLLVM-13.so
[                                                                                                                                                                                           ]
[Thread 0x7fffdb7fe640 (LWP 55076) exited]                                                                                                                                                   

Thread 7 "QDBusConnection" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffd9ffb640 (LWP 55079)]
0x00007ffff597973f in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fffc80100d0, nfds=4, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
Downloading 0.00 MB source file /usr/src/debug/glibc-2.34-12.fc35.x86_64/io/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c
29    return SYSCALL_CANCEL (poll, fds, nfds, timeout);
```

Comment: может ручками дебагинфо поставить?
https://russianblogs.com/article/33171322475/

Comment: спасибо за ответ! разобрался. в настройках был неправильный путь к компилятору clang

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. В настройках был неправильный путь к компилятору clang :-(